# На сайдбаре не вмещается кнопка подписки на рассылку на странице просмотра вопроса

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, дизайн

Если зайти в любой вопрос и посмотреть на сайдбар, то мы увидим вот такую обрезанную кнопку "Подпишитесь на информационн~":

[image: Кнопка подписки на рассылку]

Полный текст кнопки, который видно в инструментах разработчика:
"Подпишитесь на информационный бюллетень". Может быть, стоит сократить текст на кнопке до "Подпишитесь на рассылку" или до "Подпишитесь на бюллетень"? Так он точно вместится.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Похоже, что уже исправлено. Можно ставить [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

[подтверждающий скриншот (слишком большой)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4scd6.png)